# i want to set discount of product price according to product quantity buy

Tags: magento-1.9, price

When Client Select 10 Quantity price is $25
after client change it 20 Quantity price is $40
so on for 30 Quantity price is $50.

I Want to set discounted price base on quantity purchase, from admin same configuration as tier price logic

Comment: Why not using tier prices?

Comment: what about discounts for qty 11-19 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using tier price, check the screenshot below : [image]

Comment: Read question properly, He want same functionality as tier price not tier price.